# when we assign a class variable to another class variable what exactly are we doing

Tags: java

instance variables assignment

```
package projects;

public class Node {//Node class
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node leftNode;
    Node rightNode;        
}

public class Tree {//Tree class
    if (node.data < root.data) {
        focusNode = focusNode.leftNode; //what does this assignment mean //exactly
    }
}
```

This is the code snippet I need help on, please help thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure it's a duplicate of references and object. The main problem could be an (lack of) understanding of [linked lists](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the code you are asking about is missing its type and should be (see second to last line):

```
package projects;

public class Node {//Node class
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node leftNode;
    Node rightNode;        
}

public class Tree {//Tree class
    if (node.data < root.data) {
        Node focusNode = focusNode.leftNode; 
    }
```

This looks like a self-referencing node for a Tree storage system.

It is comparing the `data` of the present `node` to the `root` (assumedly the parent of the node) so that you can add the node to either the left or right side of the tree.